# Symfony Process Component - Set Input Argument for command

Tags: php, asynchronous, command, symfony

I need to run a command asynchronously. To do this, I'm trying to use Process Component.

The command I'm trying to start is calling a function that needs somes parameters. These parameters are given by Controller that launches the Process.

Problem is I don't know how to pass parameters to my command with Process Component.

Command :

```
protected function configure()
{
    $this
        ->setName('generationpdf:classement')
        ->setDescription('Génère le PDF d\'un classement.');
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    ini_set('memory_limit','4000M');
    $pdf = $this->imprimerAction();
    $this->sendClassement($pdf);
    $output->writeln('PDF envoyé.');
}
```

Controller :

```
        $command = new PDFClassementCommand();
        $input = new ArrayInput(array('id' => $id, 'errata' => $errata, 'precision' => $precision, 'group' => $group, 'logoAnnee' => $logoAnnee));
        $output = new NullOutput();

        $process = new Process($command);
        $process->disableOutput();
        $process->start();
```

Parameters I need to use are in ArrayInput but Process doesn't take array argument.

Answer (score 2):

The [process](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) is expecting first argument to be string.

Example:

```
$process = new Process('ls');
```

To run command you will need to execute symfony console command

```
$process = new Process('/var/www/my-project/bin/console generationpdf:classement')
```

> You don't have to hardcode the path, see [how-to-get-the-root-dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215753/how-to-get-the-root-dir-of-the-symfony2-application).

You can pass [parameters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/console_arguments.html) normally, like running command from cli

```
$process = new Process('/var/www/my-project/bin/console generationpdf:classement --id=5 --errata=someValue')
```

Comment: I did what you said and my command is running as intended in terminal.

I tried with Process but it doesn't work.

`$rootDir = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir();`

`$process = new Process('php '.$rootDir.'/bin/console generationpdf:classement '.$id.' '.$group.' '.$logoAnnee.' '.$errata.' '.$precision.'');`

`$process->start();`

Process is started but is not successful.

Comment: `$process->run()` is working but it doesn't execute command in background.

Comment: Could you wait the process to finish, using `start()` and then check the output and error output. There should be error output for failed process, right ? See [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#running-processes-asynchronously) for implementation.

Comment: I've just seen in logs these lines : `[2016-08-18 19:45:50] php.DEBUG: unlink(C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\sf_proc_00.out): Permission denied {"type":2,"file":"\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Process\\Pipes\\WindowsPipes.php","line":190,"level":28928} []`
`[2016-08-18 19:45:50] php.DEBUG: unlink(C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\sf_proc_00.err): Permission denied {"type":2,"file":"\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Process\\Pipes\\WindowsPipes.php","line":190,"level":28928} []`

Comment: When I add these lines : 
`$process->start();
            $process->wait()
               `

It's also working but it's blocking main process. Look like it doesn't want to get to background due to some permission but I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: It looks like some kind of [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).